# Method Reference example in JLS

Tags: java, java-8, specifications

JLS 15.13 [lists examples](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13-500) of method reference expressions.  One of them is

> `(test ? list.replaceAll(String::trim) : list) :: iterator`

which doesn't make sense since `replaceAll` is `void`.  Am I misunderstanding something or is this an error in JLS (perhaps an earlier version of `replaceAll` returned the resulting list)?

Comment: Yes, that totally looks like a bug.

Answer (score 5):

Well, technically it's not specified in JLS that the `list` variable has `java.util.List` type. So this code can be compiled with some custom type:

```
public static class MyList implements Iterable<String> {
    private final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyList add(String val) {
        list.add(val);
        return this;
    }

    public MyList replaceAll(UnaryOperator<String> op) {
        list.replaceAll(op);
        return this;
    }

    public Iterator<String> iterator() {
        return list.iterator();
    }
}

public Supplier<Iterator<String>> it(MyList list, boolean test) {
    return (test ? list.replaceAll(String::trim) : list) :: iterator;
}
```

But in general it looks like they intended to make an example based on `java.util.List`. Thus probably it would be best to replace it with something JDK-based.